# Creating new objects using a iterator in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, iterator

Here is my code first:

```
public static List<AnagramFamily> assignFamilies(List<Word> theOriginalList) {
  //Stores the list of anagram Families.
  List<AnagramFamily> anagramList = new LinkedList<AnagramFamily>();
  //TempList to store the word objects.
  List<Word> tempList = new LinkedList<Word>();
  ListIterator<Word> itr = theOriginalList.listIterator();
  Word firstWord = theOriginalList.get(0);
  int cnt = 0;
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Word secondWord = itr.next();
    if (firstWord.getMyCanonical().equals(secondWord.getMyCanonical())) {
      tempList.add(secondWord);
    } else {
        cnt++;
        Collections.sort(tempList, new WordComparatorByDesecending());
        anagramList.add(new AnagramFamily(tempList));
        System.out.println(anagramList);
        tempList.clear();
        secondWord = itr.previous();

      //create new anagram family
    }
    System.out.println("New First Word: " + firstWord + " Second Word: " + secondWord);
    firstWord = secondWord;
  }
  System.out.println(anagramList);
  return anagramList;
}
```

}

So basically what is going on here is that i am taking in a linked list of word objects which are: [abt, act, act, act, apt, apt, apt, at, ehy, ehy, ehy] Next I make a new Anagram Family object which will store it in decending order. Within the list called anagramList to where if I want I can iterate through it and print the results.

Here are the correct results:[[abt][act, act, act] [apt, apt, apt] [ehy, ehy, ehy]]

My problem here my output looks like this [[ehy, ehy, ehy], [ehy, ehy, ehy], [ehy, ehy, ehy], [ehy, ehy, ehy]]

My problem is in this line of code **anagramList.add(new AnagramFamily(tempList));** because every time it overwrites the last object. How would I do this so it doesnt overwrite it? If someone could help that would be great thankyou!

```
public class AnagramFamily {


 private List<Word> myFamilyList;
  private int myFamilySize;

  public AnagramFamily(List<Word> theFamilyList) {
    myFamilyList = theFamilyList;
    myFamilySize = myFamilyList.size();
  }
  public int getFamilySize() {
    return myFamilySize;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return myFamilyList.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: try `tempList = new LinkedList<Word>(); ` instead of `tempList.clear();`

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing `AnagramFamily`.  We need to know if `new AnagramFamily(tempList)` makes a copy of the list, or if it just stores a reference to the list.  If it stores a reference, then any change you later make to the `tempList` will also appear that way in the `AnagramFamily`, because it's pointing at the same list that you just changed.  Somewhere, somebody needs to make a copy.  Or, as @rayen said, create a new list object instead of changing the old one.

Comment: Hi @rayen, I have tried what you suggested and it almost worked! For some reason it isn't printing the last part of it which is  [ehy, ehy, ehy] Do you have any thoughts on why it would be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer would be to do `tempList = new LinkedList<Word>();` This will keep a new instance of it instead of overriding the object each time.